# Configure eclipse to open only one class

Tags: eclipse

I want to make Eclipse open only one class at a time. To be more explicit, when I double click on another class, that class will open and override the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> General -> Editors and do one of the following:

- check "Close editors automatically" and set "Number of opened editors before closing" to 1

*or*

- uncheck "Show multiple editor tabs"

Comment: Not absolutely necessary to uncheck "Show multiple editor tabs".

Comment: My suggestion was to chose one of the 2, not both. Each provides a similar thing, but in its own way